# Xamarin Froms and SkiaSharp, Hightlight an Area on Image

Tags: xamarin.forms, drawing, skiasharp, skia

I use the below code to show image on a from.

```
<ContentPage>
        <ContentPage.Content>
                <Grid>
                      // Row definitions here
                      // Column definitions here
                      <Image 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            x:Name="myStoryPage"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3">                
                      </Image>

                      <!-- Next, previous buttons here -->

                      <skiaforms:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                                PaintSurface="canvasView_PaintSurface"
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="10, 0, 5, 65"/>

                </Grid>
        </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Now I need to highlight an area in the image using SkiaSharp.
I could do drawing a line under the grid using the `SKCanvasView`. But I want to draw over the image.

I thought to use use `AbsoluteLayout` but as my page is a `ContentPage`, I could not use the `AbsoluteLayout` outside of the content.

If I could use  `AbsoluteLayout`, I can dynamically position it using `C#` in code behind.

Comment: place the canvas on TOP of the Image, then draw on the canvas with a transparent background

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, can you just share the code. Is it like <skiaforms>...</>

Comment: place a SKCanvasView in the same Grid cell as the image, so the Canvas is on Top of the Image.  If the Canvas has a transparent background, anything drawn on it will appear to be overlaid on the image

Comment: @Jason, Great, it worked. Please post as answer, I will accept it.